# How to save '<' sysmbol in MSSQL daba fetching data from the textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

this is my code....

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into " + exam + " values('" + question.Text + "','" + op1.Text + "','" + op2.Text + "','" + op3.Text + "','" + op4.Text + "','" + ans.Text + "')", conn);

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

I am passing the following line in op1(textbox)

```
<html><head></head><body><title></<title></body></html>
```

then it shows error, please tell me how to pass it...

Comment: Basically, don't do that. Use parameterized SQL instead. See http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: `follwoing line`? which line?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious where you want the "<" to be/go.

Comment: There is an extra `<` in `<title></<title>`, did you mean to put `<title></title>`?

Comment: Turn off request validtion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx  This is really dangerous.

Comment: Further reading: http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parametrized :-

```
const string sql = "INSERT INTO EXAMS VALUES (@question, @op1, @op2, @op3, @op4, @ans)";
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@question", question.text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@op1", op1.text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@op2", op2.text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@op3", op3.text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@op4", op4.text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ans", ans.text));
    foreach (var parameter in cmd.Parameters.Cast<SqlParameter>().Where(parameter => parameter.Value == null))
        parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You could simplify that by using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value)`.